# Long startup times for Chromium/Electron applications on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, brave

I'm running Brave as my default browser and using Electronmail for my mail client.

The thing is that when I boot up my PC, it takes like 15 seconds for these applications to start.
After initial startup, they open in 1 second and everything's fine.
But while they are opening (initially) they sometimes even freeze my PC.

Anyone else observe these kinds of issues?

Comment: I'd look into the way those applications start and if they perhaps start their own services/daemons in the background that are then used for faster start. As an example you can look at libre office, adobe products and so on. That's just a ballpark guess though, so it might be something completely different.

Comment: I have recently switched from the snap version of Brave browser to the one from Brave repository. The difference at start time is enormous, the repo version is about 5 times faster !  
If you have installed the snap versions, I would suggest you to try the repository one. You can refer to the Brave release channel installation instructions here : https://brave.com/linux/#linux  
For ElectronMail, there's no repo as of today, but you can find a .deb file on their GitHub : https://github.com/vladimiry/ElectronMail/releases

Comment: @FloT Yeah. The snap version of Brave is slow. (And it's noted on Brave's website). I installed the pm version and it works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, happy that it helped ! I copied the comment as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently switched from the snap version of Brave browser to the one from Brave repository. The difference at start time is enormous, the repo version is about 5 times faster !
If you have installed the snap versions, I would suggest you to try the repository one. You can refer to the Brave release channel installation instructions here : https://brave.com/linux/#linux
For ElectronMail, there's no repo as of today, but you can find a .deb file on their GitHub : https://github.com/vladimiry/ElectronMail/releases